# Dynamically added forms not saving to inlineformset_factory Django

Tags: django, formset

I have been following a variety of tutorials for a while and trying to understand/put them all together to achieve the ability for my user to dynamically add instances to a child within an inlineformset_factory.

My project is a simple employee/shifts set up. My parent model is a **ManagerChecklist** model that the manager would complete at the end of the day. The child model is an **EmployeeShift** model that contains information of each of the employees that worked on that shift and what hours they did. I would like my manager to be able to dynamically add employees to his "manager checklist" form.

views.py

```
def update_manager_checklist(request, date):
    template_name = 'shifts/checklists/manager_checklist_update.html'
    instance = get_object_or_404(ManagerChecklist, shift__shift_date=date)
    checklist = inlineformset_factory(ManagerChecklist, EmployeeShift,
                                      fields=('employee', 'start_time',
                                              'end_time', 'total_hours_worked',
                                            ),
                                      extra=0, max_num=None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = checklist(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return redirect('shifts:shift_list')

    formset = checklist(instance=instance)
    return render(request, template_name, {
        'formset': formset,
    })
```

html:

```
{{ formset.management_form }}
<div id="form_set">
    {% for form in formset %}
        <table class='no_error'>
            {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<input type="button" value="Add More" id="add_more">
<div id="empty_form" style="display:none">
    <table class='no_error'>
        {{ formset.empty_form.as_table }}
    </table>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
$('#add_more').click(function() {
    var form_idx = $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
    $('#form_set').append($('#empty_form').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_idx));
    $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_idx) + 1);
});</script>
```

The javascript is working fine to add the forms visually to the page - however they are not being validated or added or obviously sent at all to the views.py. If I update the existing forms or create an extra employeeshift using extra=1 instead of extra=0 then it is properly validating and adding that.

I am assuming I need to add some code to my views.py so that it will pick up the `formset.empty_form` that is being dynamically added? Or maybe there is a problem with the information javascript is sending to django?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

The javascript was updating the wrong TOTAL_FORMS. Instead of id_TOTAL_FORMS it should have been id_employeeshift_TOTAL_FORMS.

I'll leave for reference, as this piece of javascript was taken from a very old stack overflow answer and other people may run into the same problem.